# How to apply a function to get the encoded specific columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, label-encoding

I have this function:

```
get_class(cols):
    if cols == 1:
        return 1
    elif cols ==2:
        return 2
    else:
        return 0
```

I made a list of certain columns like this:

```
cols = ['night', 'day']
cols_en = []

for each in cols:
    each = cols + '_en'
    cols_en.append(each)
```

Here, i want the function `get_class` to apply to the `cols` and take the output in `cols_en`. I want to automate this code:

```
df ['night_en'] = [1 if x==1 else 2 if x==2 else 0 for x in df['night']]
```

Idea is to apply the function to all the columns which are in list `cols` and get the output, where the columns have the fuction `get_class` applied and output columns have `_en` at the end. Maybe using `map` function also. Any idea to achieve this? I have read several similar articles but didn't help much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you want to create a new column with 0 if the value is not 1 nor 2 in the original, for example, you can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). and create a loop over your list `cols` to create the new column

```
for col in cols:
    df[f'{col}_en'] = np.where(df[col].isin([1,2]), df[col], 0)
```

Comment: and what if there is a condition. I have value in original column from 0 to 100 and i want that 1 and 2 stay unchanged but all values which are 3 or greater than 3 convert to 3

Comment: and get the error "method object is not subscriptable"

Comment: @Arpit I don't get the error, so you need to elaborate if you want help. and for your previous comment, then it could be `np.where(df[col]<3, df[col], 3)`